# SharePoint 2013 Auto-hosted App intermittent error -- "There was a problem registering the app principal"

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, apps-development

I am trying to handle the App events and I am getting one weird **intermittent** error related to app principal.
When I try to deploy the Auto-Hosted App from visual studio, Sometime I am getting the errors below. This error is not consistent and sometime I am able to deploy my app successfully.

I thought of trying to create the token by myself, but I am getting the access denied when I try to create the token  from the location: https://microsoft.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx

```
    ErrorDetail: There was a problem registering the app principal.
    ErrorType: Configuration
    ErrorTypeName: Configuration
    ExceptionMessage: The specified application principal does not exist.
    Source: RemoteWebSite
    SourceName: Remote Web Site Deployment
```

Comment: I'm getting this relatively frequently. If you have a solution I'd love to hear it!

Comment: I use PowerShell to generate an app principal for on prem using https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/set-spappprincipalpermission?view=sharepoint-ps